# Is "any time between X happened and Y happened" correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

What I'm actually trying to say is

> This problem would also occur if someone started buying a ticket any time between the data was collected and it was published.

Or would it be

> This problem would also occur if someone started buying a ticket any time between **the time** the data was collected and it was published.

Is there a better way to say this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence needs to be

> This problem would also occur if someone started buying a ticket any
>   time between **when** the data was collected and **when** it was published.

The second sentence is okay spoken, but it's a little awkward for someone taking the time to write it out; I think this is better

> This problem would also occur if someone started buying a ticket
>   between data collection and data publication.

Fewer filler words between the important parts, which are the definitions of the two time endpoints.

or

> This problem would also occur if someone started buying a ticket
>   during the interval between data collection and data publication.